# Count the number of characters that are received in socket programming

Tags: java, string, sockets, character

This is the code for counting the number of words which works perfectly.

```
      st=new StringTokenizer(str);
        while(st.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            String s=st.nextToken();
            count++;
        }
```

What is the code for counting the number of characters?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: What does 'socket programming' add to the question? You appear to want to count the number of characters in a string... where do the sockets come into play?

Comment: Quote from the Javadoc for [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html): "`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead."

Comment: Are you interested in counting spaces? Do you know for sure if you have the right caracter set?

Answer (score 5):

Simply try this:

```
String str = "your string";
int count = str.length( );
```

The `length()` method returns the length of the string